# Output from Dynamics 365 Action Always Returning "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, output, dynamics-crm, action, dynamics-365

I have created a button that calls an action that creates an email record and returns the newly created email record id.  Please note that the email record is not the target entity.

The action looks like the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So in the above, I create the email record and then assign the entity reference from the newly created email record to my output value.

The action executes fine and creates the email record.  However, no matter what I try, the output is always undefined in js debugger.

I have tried both `XmlHttpRequest` and `Xrm.WebApi.online.execute` and both always return undefined values.  The following is my code for both:

**XmlHttpRequest:**

```
   function ltCreateIAupgradeOrAddonTemplate(executionContext, id)
    {   
        var formContext = executionContext;
        
        var serialNo = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_licenseno").getValue();
        var emailTemplateToLoad = "f22cb309-1fd9-eb11-bacb-000d3a361c51";
        var licenseId = id;
        var winFt = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_factorytalk").getValue();
        var winMobile = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_mobile911").getValue();
        var winNodes = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_node").getValue();
        var winPv = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_premiumvoice").getValue();
        var addOnsCb = [winFt, winMobile, winNodes, winPv];
        var addOns = ["WIN-911/FT", "WIN-911/Mobile", "WIN-911/Nodes", "WIN-911/PV"];
        var addOnInjectionString = "";
        
        for (let i = 0; i < addOnsCb.length; i++) 
        {
            if(addOnsCb[i] == true)
            {
                addOnInjectionString += addOns[i] + " + ";
            }       
        }
        
        addOnInjectionString = addOnInjectionString.substring(0, addOnInjectionString.length - 2);
        
        licenseId = licenseId.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");enter code here
            
            var parameters = {};
            parameters.addOnInjectionString = addOnInjectionString;
            
            var target = {entityType: "ptc_license", id: licenseId};
            parameters.entity = target;
    
                parameters.getMetadata = function () 
                {
                    return {
                        boundParameter: "entity",
                        operationType: 0,
                        operationName: "jso_LTAction",
                        parameterTypes: 
                        {   
                            "addOnInjectionString": 
                            {
                                "typeName": "Edm.String",
                                "structuralProperty": 1
                            },
                            
                            "entity":
                            {
                                "typeName": "ptc_license",                  
                                "structuralProperty": 5
                            }
                        },
                
                        operationType: 0,
                        operationName: "jso_LTAction"
                        
                    };
                }
            
        
    
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/jso_LTAction", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                alert(result);
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
    
    
        alert("IA ADDON email is ready to send.");  
    }
```

**Xrm.WebApi.online.execute:**

```
function ltCreateIAupgradeOrAddonTemplate(executionContext, id)
{   
    debugger;
    
    var formContext = executionContext;
    
    var serialNo = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_licenseno").getValue();
    var emailTemplateToLoad = "f22cb309-1fd9-eb11-bacb-000d3a361c51";
    var licenseId = id;
    var winFt = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_factorytalk").getValue();
    var winMobile = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_mobile911").getValue();
    var winNodes = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_node").getValue();
    var winPv = formContext.getAttribute("ptc_premiumvoice").getValue();
    var addOnsCb = [winFt, winMobile, winNodes, winPv];
    var addOns = ["WIN-911/FT", "WIN-911/Mobile", "WIN-911/Nodes", "WIN-911/PV"];
    var addOnInjectionString = "";
    
    for (let i = 0; i < addOnsCb.length; i++) 
    {
        if(addOnsCb[i] == true)
        {
            addOnInjectionString += addOns[i] + " + ";
        }       
    }
    
    addOnInjectionString = addOnInjectionString.substring(0, addOnInjectionString.length - 2);
    
    licenseId = licenseId.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");


        
        var parameters = {};
        parameters.addOnInjectionString = addOnInjectionString;
        
        var target = {entityType: "ptc_license", id: licenseId};
        parameters.entity = target;

 
            parameters.getMetadata = function () 
            {
                return {
                    boundParameter: "entity",
                    operationType: 0,
                    operationName: "jso_LTAction",
                    parameterTypes: 
                    {   
                        "addOnInjectionString": 
                        {
                            "typeName": "Edm.String",
                            "structuralProperty": 1
                        },
                        
                        "entity":
                        {
                            "typeName": "ptc_license",                  
                            "structuralProperty": 5
                        }
                    },
            
                    operationType: 0,
                    operationName: "jso_LTAction"
                    
                };
            }
        };
    
    Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(parameters).then(
        function success(result) {
            if(result.ok){
                result.json().then(function (results) {
                    
                    var emailId = results.emailId;
                    //Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo({pageType:"entityrecord", entityName:"email", formType: 2, entityId: emailId}, {target: 2, position: 1, width: {value: 100, unit: "%"}});
                    alert(emailId);
                
            })
                        //var results = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
//console.log(result);

    }
    else
    {
          Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Unknown error occured in ISV code.");
    }
        },
    function (error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);*/
```

**Undefined results every time:**

[image]

I've been fighting with this for a very long time now and any extra eyes will help.

Comment: This definitely has to do with the EntityReference output type.  I created another output variable and made it a string to pass a string back and worked fine.